# How to place reach row in a result set in it's own column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store results of a surveys. I have to write a procedure that will table this feedback from those surveys and insert it into a different table of the database.

The only problem in that in the new database each question has it's own column where in the source table I have them listed in rows. so each answer has a different row in the database.

I have created a fiddle of my current table along with a test feedback results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bda665/1

to be able to know the different feedback in the database the account_id, completed_by, completed_on but be the same.

from the fiddle the results should look like this

```
INSERT INTO feedback_final(Q21, Q22, Q23, Q24, Q25, Q26, Q27, Q29, completed_by, completed_on, account_id)
    Answer for Question 21 '2053'
    Answer for Question 22 'ANSWER: Describe Practice Experience with Financing'
    Answer for Question 23 '67;68;70'  -- notice here because the question_ID id the same I have to merge the results with a simi-colon
    Answer for Question 24 '7'
    Answer for Question 25 '755555'
    Answer for Question 26 '3'
    Answer for Question 27 '75'
    Answer for Question 29 'This is an action plan'
    completed_by
    completed_on
    account_id
```

This will allow me to insert each answer into a different column.

How can I approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is called a "pivot". Search SO for "[mysql] pivot" and you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: The real question is: "do you really need to do it?" Database is not an Excel spreadsheet, and a-column-per-question design is in most cases far from optimal design.